# Is it true that the derivative of an integral function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

**Let $f(x)$ be a Riemann integrable function (not neccesarily continuous) defined on some interval I. Let $F(x) = \int_a^xf(t)dt$ be it's integral function. Suppose that $F(x)$ is differentiable in the interval where it is defined, and let $F'(x)$ be its derivative. Is it true that $F'(x)$ is Riemann integrable on the interval I?**

I was wondering if this proposition is true, since the symmetric proposition is true by Barrow's Rule (FTC)

**Let $F(x)$ be a differentiable function defined on some interval I. Let $f(x) = F'(x)$ be it's derivative. Suppose that $f(x)$ is integrable in the interval where it is defined. Then $\int_a^x f(t)dt = F(x) + c$, where $c = -F(a)$**

If the first proposition its true, applying the second one we would have $\int_a^x F'(t)dt = F(x) - F(a)$

I would be grateful if the the proof is "elementary" and does not use any Measure Theory or Lebesgue integral results.

Comment: Are you familiar with the characterization that a function is Riemann integrable if and only if (1) it is bounded and (2) the set of points where it is discontinuous has measure zero? (I know you asked for a proof that avoids measure theory, but the notion of measure zero and the above-mentioned characterization do not require any significant measure theory and are often proved in books that focus on Riemann integration.)

Comment: I'm not very familiarized with the concept, but i know the result. I imagine we the can proof that $F'(x)=f(x)$ also almost everywhere (by FTC). Then $F'(x)$ is integrable because it is also continuous everywhere. However, as you said, I was looking for a complete elementary proof (completely avoiding any Measure Theory). Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: My pleasure. Hopefully someone will provide a more elementary argument. If nothing else, the one you outlined (which is what I had in mind) shows that with a bit of extra machinery, some questions related to Riemann integration become way easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We let $I=[a,b]$ and consider a partition $P=\{a=x_{0}<x_{1}<\ldots<x_{n}=b\}$ of $I$.
Next observe that for each $s,t\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$, where $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $s<t$, that

\begin{equation*}
\frac{F(t)-F(s)}{t-s}=\frac{1}{t-s}\int_{s}^{t}\!{}f(x)\mathrm{d}x
\ge\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}(f).
\end{equation*}

Letting $s$ increase to $t$ gives that

\begin{equation*}
F'(t)\ge\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}(f).
\end{equation*}

Since $t\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ was arbitrary and $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ was arbitrary we have

\begin{equation*}
\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}(F')\ge\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}(f)
\end{equation*}

for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Note that a similar proof can be used to establish this inequality at $t=x_{i-1}$. A similar proof also shows that

\begin{equation*}
\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}(F')\le\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_{i}]}(f)
\end{equation*}

for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$. We conclude that

\begin{equation*}
L(f,P)\le{}L(F',P)\le{}U(F',P)\le{}U(f,P)
\end{equation*}

where $L(g,P)$ and $U(g,P)$ denote the lower and upper Darboux sums of $g$ over $P$.
Refining the partition and using that $f$ is integrable shows that $F'$ is integrable over $I$.